# Stop Foxit Reader from showing the UAC dialog on each start

Tags: uac, foxit-reader

Recently Foxit Reader started popping up the UAC dialog on each start asking if I want to run it as administrator, and allow it to make changes to my computer.
How could I make that stop? Disabling UAC is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a foxit shortcut, right click, properties, compatibility, change for all users, and  uncheck run this program as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with the plugin loader of build 1126. It's not about elevated permissions on the shortcut it makes.

http://forums.foxitsoftware.com/forum/portable-document-format-pdf-tools/foxit-reader/42009-why-is-there-a-uac-prompt-win7-with-the-latest-version